# IBM Mobile First Platform (6.3) - Windows Phone 8 environment and Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst

I create demo app using angularjs (+ angular-ui-router) to develop and build to android, ios, windows phone 8 environment. Everythings works fine on android, ios and mobile web simulator, but on windows phone device it doesn't show my custom directive. I use visual studio express 2012 for windows phone to build.

in index.html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>test</title>
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
                <!--
                    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">
                    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/apple-touch-icon.png"> 
                -->
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
                <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
            </head>
            <body style="display: none;" ng-controller="demoController">
                <!--application UI goes here-->
                <div ui-view></div>

                <script src="js/libs/angular.js"></script>
                <script src="js/libs/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

                <script src="js/app.js"></script>

                <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
                <script src="js/main.js"></script>
                <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
            </body>
    </html>
```

In main.js:

```
 var PATH = "";
    function wlCommonInit(){
        if (WL.Client.getEnvironment() == WL.Environment.WINDOWS_PHONE_8) {
            PATH = "/www/default/";
        }
        // Common initialization code goes here
        angular.element(document).ready(function() {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
        });
    }
```

in app.js:

```
 (function() {
        angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
        // config route
        .config(function($stateProvider) {
            $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/home',
                templateUrl: PATH + 'js/templates/home.html'
            });
        })
        // custom directive
        .directive('mHeader', function() {
            return {
                templateUrl: PATH + 'js/templates/header.html'
            };
        })
        // demo controller
        .controller('demoController', function($state) {
            $state.go('home');
        });
    })();
```

in home.html:

```
<div m-header></div>
<div>this is home page</div>
```

in header.html:

```
<div>this is header</div>
```

In Visual Studio output view from debug:

```
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{42B9E91D-5EEE-40E2-8162-FDBCC185DADB}\Install\example.DLL'. Symbols loaded.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{42B9E91D-5EEE-40E2-8162-FDBCC185DADB}\Install\WLWPNativeLib.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{42B9E91D-5EEE-40E2-8162-FDBCC185DADB}\Install\worklight-windowsphone8.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\WinMetadata\Windows.winmd'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.Linq.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{42B9E91D-5EEE-40E2-8162-FDBCC185DADB}\Install\WPCordovaClassLib.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Core.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.ServiceModel.Web.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\en-US\mscorlib.debug.resources.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
The thread 0xc98 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
The thread 0x840 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0xa3c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
An exception of type 'System.SystemException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.Interop.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
The thread 0xe34 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
The thread 0x904 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0xd78 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0xd0c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0xb08 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x8b0 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0xe1c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
An exception of type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
The thread 0x44c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x460 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\Data\Programs\{42B9E91D-5EEE-40E2-8162-FDBCC185DADB}\Install\Newtonsoft.Json.DLL'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The thread 0x4b4 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Dynamic.Runtime.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Linq.Expressions.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.ObjectModel.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.IO.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Collections.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Globalization.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Runtime.Extensions.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The thread 0x364 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
```

Comment: And what error do you see in the Visual Studio output view?

Comment: Sorry, i have edited my question.

Comment: unfortunately the log does not seem to provide anything relevant. Can you provide a demo MFP project that reproduces the issue so that it could be debugged?

Comment: yes, i have uploaded project to github, https://github.com/hoangnm/exampleMBF

Comment: may be it related to this issue? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7843

Comment: This may very much be related. I suggest to open a PMR so that we will patch the Cordova version in MobileFirst Platform with it and provide you an iFix.

Answer (score 1):

The IE on Windows Phone does not allow resource injection. Adding all assignments within MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(); solves most of the jQuery and Angular JS problems. As shown below..

```html
MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function () {
    element.innerHTML = value;
});
```

Comment: i think this is not my problem in this situation, it can not call $http when change to new state using angular ui router in cordova  3.6.3 for windows phone.