# IBM MobileFirst 6.3 AngularJS routing not happening in windows phone 8.1

Tags: angularjs, windows-phone-8.1, ibm-mobilefirst

I tried all the solutions on stackoverflow changed to use absolute path and routing is still not happening in windows phone 8.1. Actually the issue is with templateUrl, the url given is not picking from the stateProvider but if i directly give template:'' it is rendering fine. I want it to work with templateUrl.

Below is my code which I got from Multi Page Sample application from IBM :multi page sample project I did some modifications it works fine with jQuery but not with AngularJS.

My code goes here:

```js
var module = angular.module("simpleApp",['ui.router','appControllers','projectControllers']).config(["$stateProvider","$urlRouterProvider",function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");

        $stateProvider.state("home",{
    url: "/home",
   templateUrl:changeTemplateUrls('home.html')
    controller: 'homeController'
     })
       .state("project1",{
        url: "/project1",
                templateUrl:changeTemplateUrls('project1.html'),
        controller: 'project1Controller' 
         });
   function changeTemplateUrls(name){
            var path = "";
    if (WL.Client.getEnvironment() == WL.Environment.WINDOWS_PHONE_8) {
        path = "www/default/";
    }
    var url = path+"app/partials/"+name;
      return url;
    }
}]);

var appControllers = angular.module("appControllers",[]);

appControllers.controller('homeController',['$scope','$state','$stateParams',function($scope,$state,$stateParams){
 $scope.greeting = "Welcome Home";
}]);

var projectControllers = angular.module("projectControllers",[]);

projectControllers.controller('project1Controller',['$scope',function($scope){
 $scope.greeting = "Welcome to Project 1";
}]);

projectControllers.controller('project2Controller',['$scope',function($scope){
 $scope.greeting = "Welcome to Project 2";
}]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-csp lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Angular Test</title>

    <!-- Uncomment for PhoneGap App -->
        <!-- <script src="cordova.js"></script> -->
        
        <!-- Link in CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/main.css" />
        
        <!-- Link jQuery, then Angular, then the rest of my scripts -->
        <script src="app/libs/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
        <script>jQuery.isUnsafe = true;</script>
        <!-- Angular Version 1.2.0 -->
        <script src="http://jsconsole.com/remote.js?VARADAUNIQUE"></script>
        <script src="app/libs/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="app/libs/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="app/libs/angular-ui-router.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
                     <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        
        <script src="app/js/main.js"></script>
        
        <script src="app/js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="app/js/controllers.js"></script>
        <!-- For Phonegap Apps, use deviceready -->
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
                angular.bootstrap(document,["simpleApp"]);
        //    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
        //  angular.bootstrap(document,["simpleApp"]);
        //},false);
            };
        </script>
    </head>
 <body>
        <nav class="simpleNav">
            <a href="#/home">Home</a>
            <a href="#/project1">Project 1</a>
            <a href="#/project2">Project 2</a>
        </nav>
        <div ui-view></div>
        <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
     <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>


<script type="text/ng-template" id="app/partials/home.html">
  <div class="home">
 <span class="message" >
  {{greeting}}
 </span>
  </div>
</script>


<script type="text/ng-template" id="app/partials/project1.html">
  <div class="project1">
 <span class="message">
  {{greeting}}
 </span>
  </div>
</script>
```

and templates are there in 
app/partials/home.html
app/partials/project1.html
index.html

I have console logged the paths in windows mobile it is coming

> www/default/app/partials/home.html

and tried

> /www/default/app/partials/home.html

and tried all the permutaion and combination of paths

but templates are not picked and home.html only itself is not loaded.

Comment: may be it related to this? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958172/ibm-mobile-first-platform-6-3-windows-phone-8-environment-and-angularjs?noredirect=1#comment46207462_28958172

Comment: This issue is resolved in IBM MobileFirst version 7.0 .. It was cordova issue. if u upgrade to MobileFirst versio 7.0 you will not face this issue with same code base . No absolute path required.

Answer (score 0):

Hey we had the same Problem we fixed it after using this.

```
.config(['$compileProvider', function($compileProvider) {
$compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|local):|data:image\//);
$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|file|local|ghttps?|ms-appx|x-wmapp0):/);
//$compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist('templates/');

}])
```

Since windows 8.1 is adding x-wampp it didnt work

Comment: Its i still not working for me . can you provide some more in formation? I have tried with both with absolute path and relative.still templates are not loading.